# Make word motions treat . (period) like space

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

```
a b.c d
^
```

If I press <kbd>w</kbd>, my cursor moves to `b`, pressing again moves it to `.`

How can I make it such that vim ignores `.` the same way it ignored the space, i.e. when cursor is at `b`, pressing <kbd>w</kbd> moves me to `c` and not `.`  I want to do this since 90% of the time when I want to move to another word with <kbd>w</kbd>, `.` is not where I intend to move to and it's so annoying to have to press <kbd>w</kbd> twice to traverse a `.`

I'd also like to do the same with a whole bunch of obvious non-words such as `()[]{}:,`

Note that `:set iskeyword+=.` does not satisfy my need as it results in pressing <kbd>w</kbd> at `b` go to `d` instead of `c` (I want it to go directly to `c`, only bypassing the `.`)

Comment: How do I migrate this to [vi stackexchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an excellent plugin by Kana Natsuno that I've been using for years now that, I think, does what you need: https://github.com/kana/vim-smartword

It doesn't ignore just `.`, it ignores any kind of punctuation. This means that the word motions, `w`, `b`, `e`, and `ge`, jump directly on the next/previous word character, instead of landing on things in the middle.

The documentation explains it best: https://github.com/kana/vim-smartword/blob/master/doc/smartword.txt#L40-L66

Comment: Nice solution, I ended up binding them to W, B, E instead of w, b, e since I wanted to retain `dw` only deleting a word, thanks!

Comment: I think `dw` still deletes just the word. There might be a special override there. I would recommend you try out `dW` in your new mapping and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the `iskeyword` setting:

> ```
> 'iskeyword'
>     Keywords are used in searching and recognizing with many commands:
>     "w", "*", "[i", etc.  It is also used for "\k" in a |pattern|.  See
>     'isfname' for a description of the format of this option.
> ```

A simple `:set iskeyword+=.` will add `.` to the list of characters considered part of a `word`. Use commas to add multiple characters, or a decimal ASCII range to specify several at once:

```
:set iskeyword+=[,],40-41    " adds []()
```

Note that some characters are special. `,`, obviously, and also `@`. See `:help 'isfname'` for full details.

`iskeyword` is a buffer local setting, and often modified as a side effect when the filetype is set, so keep that in mind. `iskeyword` can also affect syntax highlighting, unless the syntax uses `syn-iskeyword`.

Comment: Doesn't work as intended though, adding `.` as keyword makes pressing w at `b` go directly to d instead of `c`...  I wish to make it such that pressing w at `b` go to `c` instead of `.`

Comment: @Woofas Ah, I see what you mean now. I'll leave this answer in place though, as it may be useful to others.